# curl doesn't respect --connect-timeout setting

Tags: curl, pycurl

`--connect-timeout` option is ignored by curl command and pycurl library.

Reproduction:

`time curl --connect-timeout 60 ftp://ftp.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/uuid-1.6.2.tar.gz`

Can't figure out why…

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.30.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0) libcurl/7.30.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

Comment: Might be worth putting a -v in your curl command options.  Mine works as expected - times out after 1m0.838s.  curl 7.37.0 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin).  Connects very quickly to the server on port 21, then tries to connect on a different port and times out on that connection.

Comment: Indeed, it's `> RETR uuid-1.6.2.tar.gz` who lags =(